# How to show line numbers in Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

If I get a exception stack trace in Spark Shell, it shows line numbers from code in Spark shell, such as `<console>:62`.

But Spark Shell itself doesn't show line numbers, so I can not locate which line goes wrong.

Comment: I think that's a column number of the last command, not a line number

Comment: The number appears in the stack trace, I'm sure it's line number

Comment: Assuming you are writing Scala, you could write a Scala file, and pass that in with `spark-shell -i`, then you will get line numbers in your text editor

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it !